# Compare integer and float

Tags: c

I have used this code to generate root, if output is not integer it should return -1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    long int n=0;
    long int num,p,reti;
    double ret;
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    while(n!=0){
        scanf("%ld %ld",&p,&num);
        ret=pow(num,(double)1/p);
        reti=(int)ret;
        printf("%lf %lf\n",ret,(double)reti);
        if(ret!=(double)reti){
            reti=-1;
        }
        printf("%ld\n",reti);
        n=n-1;

    }
    return 0;

}
```

but if I give input as

```
1
5  3125
```

it should give `5`, but it is giving `-1`.

Comment: Please reformat your post so we can read the code in a code block.  Ie add spaces in front to each code line!

Comment: keep variable names understandable !what is n,p,num...why not keep it like number , power

Comment: what does the earlier printf line show?  I would suspect that the pow function returns something close to 5 but not exactly 5.0000000000.  (eg  5.00000000001)  Then when you (int) it and get 5 and convert this back to a double you see that 5.0000000000 != 5.00000000001.

Comment: 1/5 is not exactly representable in binary floating-point, so even if you assume that `pow()` will produce an answer within one half  ULP of the exact one *for the computation you are performing*, that answer may not be exactly 5, because the power is not exactly 0.2.

Answer (score 1):

`ret` is not exactly `5.00000`, you're just not printing enough digits after the decimal point to see the difference. Change your format to `%.20lf` and it will show `5.00000000000000088818`, which is not equal to `(double)5`.

This is because `pow()` works with floating point numbers, and there are some inaccuracies introduced. `(double)1/5` can't be represented exactly in binary floating point. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is this block of code:

```
if(ret!=(double)reti){
    reti=-1;
}
```

`reti` is some integer value - converting it to double will convert it to a double representation, but odds are good that it will not be *exactly* equal to `ret`. This is a common issue with floating point numbers - generally speaking, you should never compare pure equality. Instead, you should compare the difference between the two numbers and confirm that it's within some acceptable error range (e.g. 0.00001).